Issue with Deploying Cloud Function: Service Account Errors
I’m experiencing an issue when trying to deploy a Cloud Function on Google Cloud. And it is being deployed as Gen 1, by default I believe . My deployment command specifies a particular service account, but I’m encountering an error stating that the default service account (myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) doesn't exist, even though it does exist and is enabled.
Here's what I’ve observed:
Deployment with a Specific Service Account:
When I include the --service-account flag in the deployment command, specifying my-service-account@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com, the deployment fails with the error that the service account doesn’t exist, despite it being properly created, enabled, and set as the active account.
Deployment without Specifying a Service Account:
When I remove the --service-account flag from the deployment command, it throws an error stating that this default service account doesn’t exist. This is confusing because the default service account does exist and is enabled, and I’m unsure why it’s being used in the first place when I’ve already set a specific service account as active.
Permissions and Settings:
I've verified that both service accounts exist, are enabled, and have the necessary permissions. The myproject@appspot.gserviceaccount.com service account is active and set to Editor, so the error doesn't align with the actual state of the accounts.
Errors Encountered:
**With Specific Service Account:**ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Ok], message=[Invalid function service account requested: [my-service-account]@[myproject].iam.gserviceaccount.com. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.]
**Without Specifying a Service Account:**ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Ok], message=[Default service account '[default-service-account]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' doesn't exist. Please recreate this account or specify a different account. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.]
Steps Taken:
Verified that both the specific and default service accounts exist and are enabled.
Ensured the specific service account has the Service Account User role and other necessary permissions.
Attempted deployment both with and without specifying the service account in the deployment command.
Despite these steps, the deployment fails with the same error related to the default service account. Any help or insights into why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated.
I would add the ss of the error after implementing others recommendations.You would be able to see. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The error message
Proof of that service account being exist:
The gcloud config list
Thank you!

Please include evidence for your statements. Evidently you aren't specfying the correct accounts or the accounts correctly. Please use gcloud iam service-accounts list --project=${PROJECT} and/or gcloud iam service-accounts describe ${EMAIL} --project=${PROJECT} and gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} redacting sensitive content.

You can use --no-gen2 to force first gen.

Okay I will try doing that. Will keep you posted. Thanks!

Hi, so I tried doing that but still getting the same error. I would really appreciate if anybody can help me further. Thanks!

My suggestion  was not only that you what I suggested but that you update your question with the results. Without this information, it is unnecessarily difficult to help you.

Your deploying the Cloud Function using the shopify-product-data-handler Service Account and you're designating that this Cloud Function to run using the same Service Account shopify-product-data-handler as its identity. While possible, it's unusual. I'd encourage you consider using different identities for (a) deployment (customarily your user account); (b) runtime. Ensure that these accounts have sufficient permissions for these roles. Good luck!

Updated: deleting the existing function before deploying it also worked (gcloud functions delete {{function-name}})
Option 2: fixed by disabling the Cloud Functions API and then re-enabling:
Disable Cloud Function services:
gcloud services disable cloudfunctions.googleapis.com

If this fails as you have existing cloud functions, you can add the --force flag.
Enable Cloud Function services with
gcloud services enable cloudfunctions.googleapis.com

Deploying functions may still fail for a while as services are enabled, but this will be a different error to before.

Gotcha, thank you!
